# OTP broadcast receiver not working in fragment

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, broadcast

I have register this broadcast receiver into fragment, and waiting to read otp automatically but never reached onRecieve() method. please help.

```
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("SmsMessage.intent.MAIN");

    mIntentReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String msg = intent.getStringExtra("get_msg");
            msg = msg.replace("\n", "");
            String body = msg.substring(msg.lastIndexOf(":") + 1, msg.length());
            String pNumber = msg.substring(0, msg.lastIndexOf(":"));
            mOtp1.setText(pNumber.trim());
            if (pNumber.equalsIgnoreCase(sms)) {
                mAutoImg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    };
    getContext().registerReceiver(this.mIntentReceiver, intentFilter);
```

Comment: Use `getActivity()` instead of `getContext()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Intent Filter Wrong Used**

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
```

- I have Replace My Intent Filter and It works fine for me rest of code is working.